# Using window.draw() outside of main SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

I am using SFML and this is the first time I have really used a library but I have a decent knowledge in C++. How do I access my window functions outside of main? e.g.

```
void checkWin()
{
    if (iFilled[0] == 1 && iFilled[1] == 1 && iFilled[2] == 1) {
    RectangleShape line(Vector2f(150, 5));
    line.setPosition(10, 450);
    window.draw(line); //error window is inside of main()
    }
}



int main()
{
RenderWindow window;

window.create(VideoMode(800, 600), "Red vs. Green Peppers", Style::Close);
    //more code
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to check those tutorials from SFML's site: http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.1/ .

If you have decent knowledge in C++ you could use pointers and reference parameters:

```
    void checkWin( sf::RenderWindow &window) { ... }
```

Anyway, to show an image to the screen you need to do that in a while, because, how you wrote that, you will show that image only for 1 frame, or less, because you don't know if window is still open.

Comment: Thanks I tried a pointer but it didn't work guess I didn't do it right or should have used a refrence.

Comment: You can use pointers, but pointers are used for classes. For what you do( main() and some functions) it's good references